# foreach(string token in text.Split(";")) scans only for one value

Tags: c#, split

I am trying to get better in C# and so I thought making a simple programming language that can run basic commands like `println("Hi");` and `print("Hi");`
However, the code shown scans for one foreach() value, my C# code:

```cs
string text = File.ReadAllText(inputFile);
string[] fileText = text.Split(";");
foreach (string token in fileText) {
    if (token.StartsWith("println(") && token.EndsWith(")")) {
        if (token.Split("\"").Length == 3) {
            Console.WriteLine(token.Split("\"")[1]);
        } else {
            throw new Exception($"println(string); takes exactly 3 arguments of which {token.Split("\"").Length} were given.");
        }
    } else if (token.StartsWith("println(")) {
        throw new Exception("Syntax error");
    } else if (token.StartsWith("print(") && token.EndsWith(")")) {
        if (token.Split("\"").Length == 3) {
            Console.Write(token.Split("\"")[1]);
        } else {
            throw new Exception(($"print(string); takes exactly 3 arguments of which {token.Split("\"").Length} were given."));
        }
    } else if (token.StartsWith("print(")) {
        throw new Exception("Syntax error");
    }
}
```

My testing file:

```
print("This ");
println("is a test.");
```

I only get `This` as output.

Comment: what does text contain , did you load all lines of the file into it?

Comment: I hesitate to ask this but, since you haven't shown any code for handling multiple *lines,* are you sure you're actually doing so? The code you've shown seems to be for a single line with a semicolon separator.

Comment: @paxdiablo string text = File.ReadAllText(inputFile);

Comment: better of to use ReadLines to enumerate the lines one at a time

Comment: Notiq: added that info to the question.

Comment: Writing your own programming language is a classic way of learning programming, but using `Split` will never get you there. For starters, how would it handle a statement like `print("Hello; \"world\"");`? You need to start with something simpler, like a [parser](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165543/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stated in a comment (now in the question proper) that `text` is populated with:

```cs
string text = File.ReadAllText(inputFile);
```

That means a split based on semi-colons will give you the following strings (though the third depends on what comes *after* the final semi-colon):

```
print("This ")
<newline>println("is a test.")
<possibly-newline-but-irrelevant-for-this-question>
```

In other words, that second one does *not* start with `println(`, which is why your code is not picking it up. You may want to rethink how you're handling that, especially if you want to handle indented code as well.

I'd (at least initially) opt for stripping all white-space from the beginning and end of `token` before doing any comparisons.

Comment: Like @paxdiablo said, the value you're checking to see if it starts with "println(" is actually \r\nprintln("is a test."). `token = token.Trim()` will trim whitespace from the start and end of that string which will fix the problem. You can also split on the `Environment.NewLine` instead or `File.ReadAllLines(inputFile)` will give you an array of the lines in the file and will remove the new lines from each line in the array.

Answer (score 1):

What @paxdiablo said but the following will also work for the input shown:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile); // ReadAllLines, not ReadAllText
foreach (string line in lines) {
   var token = line.TrimEnd(new []{';'});
   // your code here
```